# On coordinate maps or projection maps

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we are given sets, non empty, $X$ and $Y$. Define $\pi : X \times Y \to X $ given by $\pi( (x,y) ) = x $. We know if $E \subseteq X  $, then

$$ \pi^{-1}(E) = \{ (x,y) \in X \times Y : x = \pi((x,y)) \in E \} $$

Next, if we are given countable collection $X_1,X_2,.... $, of non-empty sets, define $\pi_j: X_1 \times X_2 \times ... \times X_j \times ... \to X_j  $ by $\pi_j( (x_1,x_2,...,x_j,...) ) = x_j $, and the preimage is

$$ \pi_j^{-1}(E) = \{ (x_1,....) \in X_1 \times .... | x_j \in E \} $$

where $E \subset X_j $

How about if we have any collection of $X_\alpha $ and define their coordinate map as above, how can we write the preimage of a set in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It still works.  If you have an indexed collection of sets 
$\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I},$
then $\Pi_\alpha X_\alpha$ is the set of all $f:I\rightarrow \bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha$ so that $f(\alpha) \in X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in I$.  The same reasoning will work.